# I want a java program to input a string and display the occurence of each unique word without any built in method

Tags: java, arrays, string, word-count

This program I wrote to display the number of words available in the given  String. 
Now I want  the logic for `occurenceof` each word in the string without using any built in method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Test80 
 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence:[Try to ignore space at end]");
        String s=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Size of the string is "+s.length());
        int res=count(s);
        System.out.println("No of words in the given String --->>"+"  "+s+" :"+"is"+" :"+res);
    }


    private static int count(String s) {

        int count=0;
        if(s.charAt(0)!=' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
         {
            if((s.charAt(i)==' ')){
                count++;
           }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all that use the logic that if there are 'n' spaces in a sentence then the number of words will be n+1 simply;

Modify the program with if else .

In the count method do this

private static int count(String s) {

```
    int count=0;

    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
      if(s.charAt(i)==' ') count++;
    }

    return (count+1);//returning the number of words
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of built in method you should use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for that task.

```
Map<String,Integer> = new HashMap<>();
int begin_pos = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
        int count = map.containsKey(s.substring(begin_pos, i)) ? map.get(s.substring(begin_pos, i)) : 0;
        map.put(s.substring(begin_pos, i), count + 1);
        begin_pos = i+1;
    }
    else if(i == s.length() -1){
        int count = map.containsKey(s.substring(begin_pos)) ? map.get(s.substring(begin_pos)) : 0;
        map.put(s.substring(begin_pos), count + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since i am new Learner of java i have not gone that far to understand maps and hashtable, and according to the project i've got, i have to do it without using any built in method.

Comment: Thanks for your sugeestion